# Create getStream user from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

I m using below code to create a user from iOS. But getting you dont have permission error. What I have to do to create the user.

```
  Client.shared.create(user: User(name: "ab", id: "ababab")) { 
 (result) in
        if let user = try? result.get() {
            print("user got created...")

        } else if let er = result.error {
            print("got error in creating user: \(er.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create another user except the current user with userId from the Token. You have to create a new user on server side.